# Producer - consumer Scenerio. I have one producer and multiple consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, producer-consumer

When producer produce a message then it has to be consumed by all the consumer then only producer can produce second message and again all the consumer has to consume it and so on. 
I tried writing this code but its not working as per the requirement.can anyone help?

```
 package Demo3;

    import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

    public class ConsumerProducerMonitor {

        // produces items
        public synchronized void put(String item,int itemNo,String threadName) {
            if (isProduced) {
                return;

            }

            this.itemNo = itemNo;
            this.item=item;
            System.out.println(isProduced+"hujj");
            System.out.println("Producer " + threadName + " put Item: " + this.item);

            if (this.itemNo == 0) {
                isProduced = true;
                System.out.println(isProduced);
                this.notifyAll();
            }

        }
        int flag=10;
        private void consumeItems(String threadName) {
        System.out.println("hre i m");
          //  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
              if (itemNo < 0) 
                   return;

              flag--;
           // }
            System.out.println("Consumer " + threadName + " consumed Items from " + this.item);
            if (!sem.tryAcquire()) {
                System.out.println("Failed to aquire semaphore for consumer: " + threadName);
            }
        }

        // consumes item
        public synchronized int get(String threadName) {
            if (!isProduced) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Caught Interrupted Exceptino while waiting to consume item: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            if (flag == 0) {
              //  sem.release(NUM_SEMAPHORES);
                return this.itemNo;
            }

            if (isConsuming) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                    isConsuming = true;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Caught Interrupted Exceptino while waiting to consume item: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            switch (sem.availablePermits()) {
                case 1:
                    if (threadName.equals("C10")) {
                        System.out.println("reaching");
                        consumeItems(threadName);
                        if (threadName.equals("C10")) {
                            sem.release(NUM_SEMAPHORES);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (threadName.equals("C9")) {
                        consumeItems(threadName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (threadName.equals("C8")) {
                        consumeItems(threadName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (threadName.equals("C7")) {
                        consumeItems(threadName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (threadName.equals("C6")) {
                        consumeItems(threadName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 6:
                    if (threadName.equals("C5")) {
                        consumeItems(threadName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 7:
                    if (threadName.equals("C4")) {
                        consumeItems(threadName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 8:
                    if (threadName.equals("C3")) {
                        consumeItems(threadName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 9:
                    if (threadName.equals("C2")) {
                        consumeItems(threadName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 10:
                    if (threadName.equals("C1")) {
                        consumeItems(threadName);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
          //  isConsuming = false;
            this.notifyAll();
            return flag;
        }

        private static int NUM_SEMAPHORES =10;
        private final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(NUM_SEMAPHORES);
        private boolean isProduced = false;
        private boolean isConsuming = false;
        String item;
        int itemNo;
    }





    package Demo3;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class ConsumerProducer5 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConsumerProducer5 cp = new ConsumerProducer5();
            cp.StartconsumerProducer();
        }


        public void StartconsumerProducer() {
            ConsumerProducerMonitor mon = new ConsumerProducerMonitor();
            List threads = new ArrayList();
            Vector sharedQueue = new Vector();
            // Create a producer
            Thread p1 = new Thread(new Producer5(sharedQueue,mon,20), "P1");
            p1.start();
            // Create consumer 1
            Thread c10 = new Thread(new Consumer5(mon,sharedQueue), "C10");
            c10.start();
            System.out.println("working");
            // Create consumer 2
            Thread c2 = new Thread(new Consumer5(mon,sharedQueue), "C2");
            c2.start();
            System.out.println("working321");
            // Create consumer 3
            Thread c3 = new Thread(new Consumer5(mon,sharedQueue), "C3");
            c3.start();
            Thread c4 = new Thread(new Consumer5(mon,sharedQueue), "C4");
            c4.start();
            Thread c5 = new Thread(new Consumer5(mon,sharedQueue), "C5");
            c5.start();
            Thread c6 = new Thread(new Consumer5(mon,sharedQueue), "C6");
            c6.start();
            Thread c7 = new Thread(new Consumer5(mon,sharedQueue), "C7");
            c7.start();
            Thread c8 = new Thread(new Consumer5(mon,sharedQueue), "C8");
            c8.start();
            Thread c9 = new Thread(new Consumer5(mon,sharedQueue), "C9");
            c9.start();
            Thread c1 = new Thread(new Consumer5(mon,sharedQueue), "C1");
            c1.start();
            threads.add(p1);
            threads.add(c1);
            threads.add(c2);
            threads.add(c3);
            threads.add(c4);
            threads.add(c5);
            threads.add(c6);
            threads.add(c7);
            threads.add(c8);
            threads.add(c9);
            threads.add(c10);


            for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) {
                try {
                    ((Thread)threads.get(i)).join(20000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


package Demo3;

import java.util.Vector;

public class Consumer5 implements Runnable {
    private final Vector sharedQueue;
    Consumer5(ConsumerProducerMonitor mon,Vector sharedQueue) {
        this.mon = mon;
        this.sharedQueue=sharedQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("coming hre");
        int ret=1;
        while (ret >= 1) {
            ret = mon.get(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            while (ret == 1) {
            synchronized (sharedQueue) {

                    try {
                        sharedQueue.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    sharedQueue.notifyAll();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private final ConsumerProducerMonitor mon;
}

package Demo3;

import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



public class Producer5 implements Runnable {
    ConsumerProducerMonitor mon;
    private final Vector sharedQueue;
    private final int SIZE;

    public Producer5(Vector sharedQueue,ConsumerProducerMonitor mon, int size) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
        this.SIZE = size;
        this.mon=mon;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println("Produced: " + i);
         //   mon=new ConsumerProducerMonitor();


            try {
                produce(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Producer5.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

    private void produce(int i) throws InterruptedException {

        //wait if queue is full
        while (sharedQueue.size() == 1) {
           synchronized (sharedQueue) {
                  System.out.println("Queue is full " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                    + " is waiting , size: " + sharedQueue.size());

                sharedQueue.wait();
           }
        }

        //producing element and notify consumers
        synchronized (sharedQueue) {
            sharedQueue.removeAllElements();
            sharedQueue.add("Message No."+i);
            mon.put(sharedQueue.get(i).toString(),i, Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println(sharedQueue);
            sharedQueue.notifyAll();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh Knuth, a new semester just started, didn't it?

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of stuff in your code that is not needed. We can accomplish the task in hand with much less.

Essentially the concept here is that the producer produces the product, notifies all the consumers and then waits itself.

The consumers on the other hand, consume the product each and wait till the last consumer consumes the product, recognises that it is the last consumer and notifies the producer to start producing.

Here's the code to handle your requirements.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ProducerConsumerMultiple {

static Queue<String> sharedQueue = new LinkedList<>();

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Producer producer = new Producer("Producer1");
    Consumer consumer1 = new Consumer("Consumer1");
    Consumer consumer2 = new Consumer("Consumer2");
    Consumer consumer3 = new Consumer("Consumer3");
    Consumer consumer4 = new Consumer("Consumer4");
    Consumer consumer5 = new Consumer("Consumer5");
    new Thread(producer).start();
    new Thread(consumer1).start();
    new Thread(consumer2).start();
    new Thread(consumer3).start();
    new Thread(consumer4).start();
    new Thread(consumer5).start();
}

public static class Producer implements Runnable {
    String producerName;
    AtomicInteger itemNameCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public Producer(String producerName) {
        this.producerName = producerName;
    }

    public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (sharedQueue) {
            System.out.println(producerName + " has produced item" + itemNameCounter.incrementAndGet());
            sharedQueue.add("item" + itemNameCounter.get());//adding the product to the queue
            sharedQueue.notifyAll();
            sharedQueue.wait();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                produce();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Consumer implements Runnable {
    String consumerName;
    static AtomicInteger totalConsumersCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static Integer consumptionCountForItem = 0;

    public Consumer(String consumerName) {
        this.consumerName = consumerName;
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (sharedQueue) {
            if (sharedQueue.size() <= 0) {
                sharedQueue.wait();
            }

            System.out.println(consumerName + " has " + "consumed " + sharedQueue.peek());// Consumer is consuming the item.

            if (++consumptionCountForItem == totalConsumersCount.get()) {
                sharedQueue.remove();
                sharedQueue.notifyAll();
                consumptionCountForItem = 0;
            }
            sharedQueue.wait();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        totalConsumersCount.incrementAndGet();
        while (true) {
            try {
                consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                totalConsumersCount.decrementAndGet();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```